# why polling of Apollo useQuery don't call onCompleted?

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I am playing around the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-framework-uldf4q?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { gql } from "apollo-boost";
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/react-hooks";

const GET_DOG_PHOTO = gql`
  query Dog($breed: String!) {
    dog(breed: $breed) {
      id
      displayImage
    }
  }
`;

const breed = "dingo";

const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  const { loading, error, data, startPolling, stopPolling } = useQuery(
    GET_DOG_PHOTO,
    {
      variables: { breed },
      onCompleted: () => {
        setCount((count) => count + 1);
      }
    }
  );

  if (loading) {
    return <h2>loading</h2>;
  }
  if (error) {
    return <h2>Whoops</h2>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1> {count}</h1>
      <Fragment>
        <img
          alt="Cute Doggo"
          src={data.dog.displayImage}
          style={{ height: 500, width: 500 }}
        />
        <button onClick={() =>startPolling(500)}>Start</button>
        <button onClick={stopPolling}>Stop</button>
      </Fragment>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

In my code, I setCount to count+1 using React.useState in the onCompleted callback? why it just stop counting when polling?

so what is the mechanism here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can also observe that the `onCompleted` callback is not invoked as expected in the reproducer you provide.

In your CodeSandbox, you are using a 3-year-old deprecated version of the `useQuery` hook. You could migrate to the latest `@apollo/client` package, which will solve the issue.

See this migrated CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/apolllo-on-completed-n9wzge

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `notifyOnNetworkStatusChange` option as `true`. It will change the loading state as well every time.

Call api as

```
const { loading, error, data, startPolling, stopPolling } = useQuery(
    GET_DOG_PHOTO,
    {
      variables: { breed },
      notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
      onCompleted: () => {
        setCount((count) => count + 1);
      }
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Apollo 3.8+, `onCompleted` only gets called when `notifyOnNetworkStatusChange` is set to `true`. **However**, this is not ideal because it calls `onCompleted` several times per second, regardless of the `pollInterval` that you set. You're better off placing the contents of `onCompleted` in a `useEffect()`, with `data` as a dependency.

```js
const { loading, error, data, startPolling, stopPolling } = useQuery(
  GET_DOG_PHOTO,
  {
    variables: { breed }
  }
);

useEffect(() => {
  setCount((count) => count + 1);
}, [data]);
```